# Sequenced indexing of duplicate elements in a list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, indexing

I have a list that is:

> a = [100, 200, 200, 400, 500, 600, 600, 700, 900, 1000, 400, 200, 500]

if I try to find indices of the values in 'a' using:

```
xlist=[]
for value in a:
    x = np.array(a.index(value), value)
    xlist.append(x)
print(xlist)
```

it gives me

> xlist = [0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8, 9, 3, 1, 4]

Instead I want a list that gives me unique indices for every repeated value as well. Something like this:

> xlist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

Something that jumps the index if it's already used and moves on to index the next duplicate value and does it further.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
In [1030]: a = [100, 200, 200, 400, 500, 600, 600, 700, 900, 1000, 400, 200, 500]
In [1036]: idx = []

In [1037]: for index, val in enumerate(a):
      ...:     idx.append(index)

In [1038]: idx
Out[1038]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

OR use `list comprehensions` for a 1-line command:

```
In [1042]: idx = [index for index,val in enumerate(a)]
```

Works for both python2 and python3.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are overthinking this. Duplicates or not, you seem to just want a list going from `0` to the last index of `a`.

If that's the case, simply issue

```
>>> list(range(len(a))) # Python 3
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

or

```
>>> range(len(a)) # Python 2
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```